# Laravel 5.1 Snappy problems with Authentication

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-snappy

I am using Barrydvh\Snappy for PDF generation on my Laravel 5.1 application.
The PDF must be generated once the user has logged in, as that view must be kept private.

It seems that the shell opened by wkhtmltopdf creates a parallel session, therefore there is no user authenticated, and I get back the login route instead of the desired private view.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thank you all in advance.

Best regards,
Marta

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by having Snappy reference a view rather than a route. That way I avoided having to deal with the authentication.

```
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('viewName', compact($data));
    return $pdf->download('name.pdf');
```

I had to edit the hosts file on server to add 127.0.0.1 referencing my application domain.